# Adjusting values in MySQL based on current value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My database is for keeping track of user's balances, and there are certain actions that will add or remove balance from the users. Currently I am doing this to get the balance and update it

```php
$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=:uid")
$conn->bindValue(':uid', $data['id']
$conn-execute()
$currentBal = $conn->fetch()
$newBal = $currentBal['balance'] + 100
$conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET balance=:bal WHERE userid=:uid")
$conn->bindValue(':bal', $newBal)
$conn->bindValue(':uid', $data['id']
```

Is there a way to directly do math within the query to add or remove? It is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do arithmetic:

```
UPDATE users
   SET balance = balance + :inc
    WHERE userid = :uid;
```

You can hardcode the `100`, but I think it is better to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, and this gets around the issue in the OPs original code where two people could attempt to update the same user balance at the same time and find that only one is recorded. If there is an associated transaction such as an invoice or credit note, OP needs to look at transactions to ensure that either all tables or no tables are updated.